# let vim open two files simultaneously in split

Tags: vim

I am currently trying to get my head around vim and so far I am learning quite a lot! There is one thing though I have not yet succeeded in:

How do I have vim open two files simultaneously if they match a certain criteria?

The most prominent example would be Objective-C where I usually work with .h and .m files. It makes sense to show them up together in a split because they both form a unit.

In my current project I have a similar situation. I have a frontend project with reactjs using components, like

```
src/
  components/
    Header/
      index.jsx
      styles.scss
```

If I open index.jsx I would very much like to have the styles.scss open up in a split, too. Is this achievable? Or is there a plugin I have not found yet that does that?

Edit:
I use vim for my project in the way that I have it started from my projects root. I don't think (but maybe I am wrong here, I am quite new to vim) that it is a good workflow to open a subfolder from my project, edit, close vim, and open the next subfolder in vim... So: vim has access to all my project files, I open up a specific index.jsx and if there is a styles.scss inside the same folder than show me that, too, inside a split.

Comment: DId you mean to open all files in a folder? Or, How do you correlate them?

Comment: @SibiCoder I meant it this way: I am opening vim in my projects root folder. And whenever I open a specific jsx file from within my project that happens to have a correlating styles.scss inside the same folder then I want that styles.scss to open up in a split. Like what Xcode does (if activated) for correlating .h and .m files.

Comment: Actually look into Ctrlp or fzf plugins. I am not the biggest pro in vim, but always closing your vim sounds like pain for me. I only close it when i switch projects. And even without plugins, why not just use :e to open the new files ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Because this would mean more typing and I don't want that ;) I want this to happen automatically. I am already using fzf, by the way. I guess I can check if fzf grants me what I want but I guess that it won't.

Comment: I guess, so far, that the best solution would be https://github.com/vim-scripts/a.vim - maybe I need to fork and extend this.

Comment: @hurrtz no it won't. but you can use fzf to open files really fast without much typing. Are you using it inside vim ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with auto-commands, to put in your vimrc:

```
function! CheckAndSplit(filename)
    if !filereadable(a:filename) | return | endif
    exe 'split' a:filename
endf

au BufReadPost *.m  call CheckAndSplit(expand('%:r').'.h')
au BufReadPost index.jsx  call CheckAndSplit(expand('%:p:h').'/styles.scss')
```

Comment: This is quite close to what a.vim basically does. So far this works perfectly, thanks! But I guess I should still extend a.vim enable what I want.

Answer (score 1):

automatically ? then i think you need a plugin, or write one. Manually ? yes, you can just pipe them together like this:

```
:split index.jsx | split styles.css
```

or you could try something like this in your vimrc but it is untestet, and will need some exception handling:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.jsx :sp %:h/styles.css<CR>
```

Comment: BufReadPost looks very promising, I will look into that and see if this works!

Comment: look at the code of @yolenoyer as he has what seems like the complete logix you need.

Answer (score 1):

See vim options:

`-o[N]                Open N windows (default: one for each file)
-O[N]                Like -o but split vertically`

Example: `vim -O components/Header/*` opens `index.jsx` and `styles.scss` simultaneously in vertical splits.

[Also checkout this question](https://superuser.com/questions/486532/how-to-open-files-in-vertically-horizontal-split-windows-in-vim-from-the-command)

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect a bit more as to what I am trying to achieve. Opening a specific folder with vim is not my intention. I want to have vim work over the entire project folder. Your suggestion seems be a bit complicated in a working project with hundreds of component folders...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try to open the folder itself.

```
vim src/components/Header
```

This will list down the files under `Header` directory. You can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on any file and vim will open that file in a buffer. To go back to the directory listing press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>6</kbd> simultaneously.

Basically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>6</kbd> will take you to the last buffer which was active before the current one.

Also, once you have one file opened in a buffer, to open another file in split window, try

```
:vsplit filename
```

Or

```
:split filename
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: If I have to enter something or type something than this is not good enough. vim enables me to be quite lazy and I intend to honour that ;) I want the correlating file to open up absolutely without any additional keystroke from my part. But thank you for the suggestion!